# Selector resolved to hidden - playwright and <input> with display: none. Can anyone know how to make it work?

Tags: javascript, dom, playwright

Selector has display: none.

Im using playwright to send file like this:

```
await page.setInputFiles(
'//*[@id="root"]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/input',
file);
```

And this is error I get:

> waiting for selector
> "//*[@id="root"]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/input"   selector
> resolved to hidden

Do you know how to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the latest Playwright version? If I remember correctly a related bug got fixed in the last few releases. If not, I recommend to create a bug on GitHub with a repro: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright

Answer (score 1):

When your input element is hidden, file chooser dialog is typically triggered by some action. You can start listening to the filechooser event on page and trigger the file selection (typically press some button in the ui that brings up file selection dialog). This use case is discussed in the doc, last paragraph: https://playwright.dev/docs/input#upload-files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display property of the element using the `evaluate` method.

```
let inputFileSelector = await page.$('xpath=//*[@id="root"]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/input');
await inputFileSelector.evaluate((el) => el.style.display = 'inline'); // or inherit
```

Or you can also do this directly as

```
await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector('mySelector').style.display = 'inline'; });
```